# How to specify minmal distance between coordinates returned by OSRM

Tags: gps, osrm

I am having a route consisting of 2 points

I would like to find all GPS coordinates in the route but I want get GPS coordinate every 4 km... Is this possible please? I am lost here, I want to use this:

https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md

What I tried is used route service

http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/49.209243,18.757936;48.158645,17.106259?steps=false&geometries=geojson&overview=full&annotations=true

But how to specify the distance? or at least how could I specify that I want only 40 GPS points?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify how many points you want returned, or how far apart they should be. I believe you would need to perform this operation in your own code after requesting ALL the points from OSRM. Because you have specified `annotations=true` in your request you will receive data about the distance for each Waypoint. Using this you should be able to process the data to only contain one Waypoint every 4km.